# Building a random list

Tags: racket

I am trying to write a function that takes in the length of a list and a maximum number value and returns a list that is the length given with  numbers between 1 and the given max randomly.

so far I have

```
(define (randomlist n max)
(cond
  [(= n 0)empty]
  [else
      (cons (build-list n (random 1 max))
            (randomlist max (- n 1)))]))
```

I get an error when I run this and was wondering if anybody could help me out.

Comment: It would help to know what error you get.

Comment: Why do you switch the order of `n` and `max`?

Answer (score 4):

One can also use `for/list` to combine loop and list formation:

```
(define (randomlist n mx)
  (for/list ((i n))
    (add1 (random mx))))
```

Testing:

```
(randomlist 5 10)
```

Output:

```
'(5 9 10 4 7)
```

(random numbers, hence output is very likely to be different each time).

Answer (score 2):

There are several bugs in your code:

- It's a bad idea to call a parameter `max`, that clashes with a built-in procedure. So I renamed it to `mx`.
- There's absolutely no reason to use `build-list`, that's not how we build an output list, just `cons` one element with the rest.
- `random` receives zero or one parameters, not two. The single-parameter version returns an integer in the range `0..n-1`, hence we have to add `1` to the result to be in the range `1..n`.
- You switched the order of the parameters when recursively calling `randomlist`.

This should take care of the problems:

```
(define (randomlist n mx)
  (cond
    [(= n 0) empty]
    [else
     (cons (+ 1 (random mx))
           (randomlist (- n 1) mx))]))
```

It works as expected:

```
(randomlist 5 10)
=> '(10 7 1 4 8) ; results will vary, obviously
```

Comment: @JohnC if this or any other answer solves your problem, don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it ;) it's simple, just click on the check mark to its left.